# CDN Endpoints Rule Engine

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure

I keep getting this error

```
Error: Unsupported block type

  on cdn\main.tf line 18, in resource "azurerm_cdn_endpoint" "example":
  18:   delivery_rule {
Blocks of type “delivery_rule” are not expected here.
```

Unsure why it doesn’t like the block.

```
resource "azurerm_cdn_endpoint" "*" {

  name                = "example"
  profile_name        = azurerm_cdn_profile.example.name
  location            = "Global"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  origin_host_header = "*"
  origin {
    name      = "Example-Web"
    host_name = "*"
  }

  delivery_rule {
      name = "HttpsRedirect"
      order = 1
  request_scheme_condition  {
          match_values = ["HTTP"]
          operator = "Equal"
      }
  url_redirect_action {
          redirect_type = "Found"
          protocol = "Https"
      }
  }
Am using azurerm provider =2.0.0
```

Can someone point me in the right direction? The block seems to be in the correct place, I'm unsure why this isn't able to deploy.

There is hardly any information online regarding rules_engine for terraform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work with `azurerm` provider `=2.0.0`, you could bind the lastest provider  like this or leave out the version:

```
provider "azurerm" {
        
     features {}
    
     version = "=2.32.0"
      
}
```

Also, `global_delivery_policy` and `delivery_rule` are only allowed when `Standard_Microsoft` SKU is used. Ensure that you have `sku = "Standard_Microsoft"` in your
`azurerm_cdn_profile`.